# Using dynamic labels Morris Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, morris.js

I am using the Morris Bar Chart to display the product sales. I would like to have dynamic label ( on hovering). I am getting the data through PHP.

```
array('product' => $row['productid'], 'sales'=> $row['freq'], 'name' => $product_name);
```

and my Jquery code is here :

```
$.getJSON('getdata.php?command=product_sales', function(data) 
    {
    //var product_name = data.name;
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'morris-product-sales-chart',
            data: data,
            xkey: ['product'],
            ykeys: ['sales'],
            labels: ['Product Name'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true

        });
    });
```

If you notice, the labels are hardcoded to 'Product Name', However, I would like it to be dynamic ( 'name' attribute in PHP ). Any idea how it can be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am understanding correctly (got here looking for something else), but this should work:

```
labels: [<?=$name?>]
```

I use something similar in mine where I am pulling the table data (including a list of product names) from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Absoluteley! Let assume you have a variable which has the Morris object

```
var achart = Morris..Bar({
        element: 'morris-product-sales-chart',
        data: data,
        xkey: ['product'],
        ykeys: ['sales'],
        labels: ['Product Name'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true

    });
});
```

you can set labels as achart.options.labels =  and then do the redraw to render the updates.